# Eclipse and How it Handles JARS -- Odd Case

Tags: eclipse, apache, jar, velocity

Trying to make some small changes to Apache's Velocity engine.

Here's what I can and can't do.

I'm making a change to the merge function(). The change I'm making doesn't matter because I haven't made it yet. ;) Right now I am settling for a println statement firing.

I have two references to merge(). If I change the function to mergeBAD() Eclipse tells me that it can't find merge(). Makes sense right? I used to include in my class build path the two jars that you get when downloading velocity but instead I've created a project using the src files provided and used THAT project as a dependency. Again, the fact that is can't find merge() when I rename it to mergeBAD gives me hope.

But when I am running my web server, hit a breakpoint and step into the merge call, it can't find the source! I point it to the project yet again, and it "finds" the source, none of the changes I've made (specifically the println statements) are hit. They are simply skipped over. :(

What on God's green earth could possibly be causing this? It's driving me insane. I've spent the entire day today trying to figure out what's wrong. I can't continue without being able to change Velocity. Exactly what code base is eclipse running the velocity files from?

Many thanks in advance SO! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical case of confusion between *build classpath* and *runtime classpath*.

Your *build classpath* contains references to your Java project (containing the changes to Velocity)... but I bet your *runtime classpath* holds references to the original Velocity JAR files.

Managing *build classpath* and *runtime classpath* in Web projects under Eclipse (the WTP - Web Tools Project) has been going through massive changes over the last few WTP releases. We can guide you through. If you physically added Velocity's JAR files into your `WEB-INF/lib`, lets start by removing them.

---

OK, after you remove the `Velocity.jar` file from `WEB-INF/lib`, do the following:

1. Right-click the project, select "Properties".
2. Go to "Java build path". Select the "projects" tab and make sure that your custom Velocity project (lets call it "MyVelocity") is *NOT* there.
3. Still in "Java build path", select the "Libraries" tab and make sure that no Velocity JAR is there either.

By following the steps above, we cleaned your Web-App from any reference whatsoever to MyVelocity (your project) or any other Velocity JAR.

Now comes the fun part. I will instruct you how to correctly "add" Java projects to Web projects as dependencies.

1. Still in the project's properties, go to `Deployment Assembly`.
2. Click "Add".
3. Select "Project" and then "Next".
4. Select "MyVelocity" and make sure that the "Web Library Reference" checkbox is checked.
5. Click "Finish".

Back in the `Deployment Assembly` dialog, you should now see `MyVelocity` mapped into `WEB-INF/lib/MyVelocity.jar`.

Click OK.

What we did by that is to map MyVelocity as a `WEB-INF/lib` dependency. By doing that, `MyVelocity` is automatically added to the compile-time build-path as well - so it is *very* important that you don't add it yourself to the build-path, resulting in duplicate build-path entries.

Everything should work for you now. Let me know if you have any problems.

P.S. these instructions are correct if you're developing a stand-alone WAR project; if your WAR file is a part of an EAR, you may wish (under certain circumstances, for example if `MyVelocity` is used by other J2EE modules inside the EAR) to map `MyVelocity` differently, to a common location; if that's the case, let me know and I'll elaborate further.

Comment: Snap! :) Heading home for the day but will do this first thing tomorrow!! ^_^

Comment: I've removed the velocity-1.5.jar that was in my WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Good. Now verify for us that your WebApp does *not* work. It should fail with a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Once you do that, now is the time to configure your project to include your new, "custom" Velocity Java project inside WEB-INF/lib. I'll edit my initial answer with details how to do that.

Comment: I cannot find the dialog in the project's properties for "Deployment Assembly". Does this mean I don't have a stand-alone WAR project?

Comment: I suspect you're using an outdated version of WTP. Make sure you run the latest Eclipse - "Helios" (3.6) should do.

Comment: I am indeed using the newest version of Eclipse. :)

Comment: In that case, I suspect your project isn't set up as a "Dynamic Web Project". Right-click the project, go to "Project Facets"; if your project is (as it should be) a Dynamic Web project, you should see "Dynamic Web Module" in the list of facets. Do you?